# Setting Framebuffer's Depth/Stencil Buffer on Android OpenGL ES 3.1

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-3, android-graphics

I'm trying to attach a depth and stencil buffer to a frame buffer. I'm doing this as follows:

```
int[] bufferHandle = new int[1];
GLES31.glGenRenderbuffers(1, bufferHandle, 0); // glError = 0 (GL_NO_ERROR)
GLES31.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES31.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES31.GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);  // glError = 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
GLES31.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES31.GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0); //  // glError = 0 (GL_NO_ERROR)
GLES31.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GLES31.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES31.GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GLES31.GL_RENDERBUFFER, bufferHandle);  // glError = 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION)
```

The `glRenderbufferStorage` and `glFramebufferRenderbuffer` calls return 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION). Any ideas what I might be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occur, because the render buffer  object is not created.

[`glGenRenderbuffers`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glGenRenderbuffers.xhtml) generates a unused name respectively reserves a name, which can be used for a render buffer, but it doesn't create or bind the render buffer object. For this you've to call [`glBindRenderbuffer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glBindRenderbuffer.xhtml):

```java
int[] bufferHandle = new int[1];
GLES31.glGenRenderbuffers(1, bufferHandle, 0);
GLES31.glBindRenderbuffer(GLES31.GL_RENDERBUFFER, bufferHandle[0]);
GLES31.glRenderbufferStorage(GLES31.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GLES31.GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, width, height);
```

Note, the render buffer object is created, when `glBindRenderbuffer` is called the first time, bside that the object is bound to the specified target.
[`glRenderbufferStorage`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glRenderbufferStorage.xhtml) establishes the format and size of the data storage.

Comment: Uhg, I don't know how I missed that. Thank you very much for the help!